# Why doesn't my Norwegian ispell dictionary work on Emacs (Windows)?

Tags: ispell

I have installed the English ispell dictionary `english.hash` for using in Emacs, and placed it at `C:\Users\espend\AppData\Roaming`. When typing `M-x ispell-change-dictionary`, in Emacs, this English dictionary become available as an option to chose.

In contrast, I am not able to get the Norwegaian dictionary available within Emacs. This dictionary has another name format than the English one, and come in two files, respectively, `nb_NO.dic` and `nb_NO.aff`. When these two files are placed at the same location as the English dictionary, they are not available for Emacs by the `M-x ispell-change-dictionary` command. Hence, I cannot turn to Norwegian spell checking when I need it.

What have I done wrong?
Thanks in advance to those solving this problem for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Norwegian dictionary is for a different spell-checking application. Hunspell (available from [ezwinports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/)) should be able to handle those types of file.