# Norwegian spell check

Tags: spacemacs, ispell, spell-checking, hunspell

I'm trying to get Norwegian spell checking working in Emacs, and I'm having trouble with the Norwegian dictionary.

### System

- `Ubuntu 17.04`
- `GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.31) of 2017-02-05` (installed with Nix)
- Also tried with `GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.11) of 2017-03-29, modified by Debian` (installed with Apt-get)
- `Spacemacs v.0.200.9`

I use the Spacemacs layer `spell-checking` for spell checking. This "just works" for text in English.

### Things I've tried

1. Activate the Spacemacs layer `spell-checking`. Spell checking English text now "just works".
2. I `M-x ispell-change-dictionary` and pick `norsk` from the menu suggestions. This shows up in `*Messages*`:

   ```
   Local Ispell dictionary set to norsk
   Starting new Ispell process /usr/bin/aspell with norsk dictionary...
   Error in post-command-hook (flyspell-post-command-hook): (error "Error: The file \"/usr/lib/aspell/norsk\" can not be opened for reading.")
   ```
3. I check the folder, finding filenames not matching:

   ```
   $ ls /usr/lib/aspell | grep no
   no.dat
   no.multi
   no_phonet.dat
   norwegian.alias
   ```
4. The documentation for the `ispell` minor mode recommends installing Ispell. I install the Norwegian ispell dictionary, same error as above.
5. [Another answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/why-doesnt-my-norwegian-ispell-dictionary-work-on-emacs-windows) recommends installing hunspell. I install the Norwegian hunspell dictionary, same error as above.
6. I also installed the Norwegian aspell dictionary. Same error as above.

Any suggestions? Any relevant information I can provide?

Comment: I suspect the issue fom the post-command hook. Do other dictionaries works?

Comment: English checking works as expected. I'll try a few others and report back.

Comment: After installing the German Aspell dictionary (`sudo apt install aspell-de`), spell checking for German works.

Comment: I don't know where the problem comes from. I installed aspell-no and got the same result. I'm tempted to change the name of the files?

Comment: I haven't tried that (yet).

Should the possible options to select from the `ispell-change-dictionary` match the contents of `/usr/lib/aspell` or a different system folder?

Comment: I apologise my knowledge is limited here. Have a look in the belly of the beast. `C-h f ispell-change-dictionary`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59043/discussion-between-djj-and-teodor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble seems to be with `ispell`. I managed to get around it by using
`hunspell` instead.

1. Install Hunspell and its Norwegian dictionary

   ```
   sudo apt install hunspell hunspell-no
   ```
2. Configure Emacs to use Hunspell for spell checking

   - Set the variable **Ispell program name** to `hunspell`
3. Use the Norwegian dictionary

   - `M-x ispell-change-dictionary` then `nb_NO`